# JQuery Hover & fade on an image with mousemove

Tags: jquery

I've got three images all the same size. If a user moves to the left, one image is loaded (showing the section on the left in colour) and if he moves to the right, the right is coloured. I want the images to fadein and out adding a nice effect.

I've tried this and I cannot get it to work! I'm using mouseenter and a few other functions but I cannot get it working. Images are here: http://bit.ly/1vjRQnS

Regards,

Nik

Comment: I don't really got what you want to achive? Could you please explain it a little bit more and give some code?

Comment: Yes of course: 1) when user comes to the page they see the NoRollover image. 2)If they hover to the left side of this image, the Left image loads (highlighting the bottle) 3)if they hover to the right the Right image loads(highlighting the other bottle).

Comment: I haven;'t added code as I don't think I'm doing it right, I'd prefer you guys to guide me. 1)I created three divs and used the z-index to try and achieve this. 2) I also tried one div with three <img /> tags and tried changing the src using JS but I couldn't achieve the fadeIn of the images so ideally if you start me off that would really help! Thanks!

Comment: But dude, you have no code at all , anyway i'll try to create some example for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's first version not perfect, could be done many other better ways 
But as fast I could it is

```
    $("div.wrapper").css({
    height: $("img").height(),
    width: $("img").width()
  });

  $("div.wrapper").hover(function(){


    $("div.First").hover(function(){
      $(".left").stop().fadeIn();
      $(".none, .right").stop().fadeOut();

    }, function(){
      $(".left").fadeOut();
    });
    $("div.Second").hover(function(){
      $(".right").stop().fadeIn();
      $(".none, .left").stop().fadeOut();

    }, function(){
      $(".right").stop().fadeOut();
    });

  },function(){
     $(".left, .right").stop().fadeOut();
     $(".none").stop().fadeIn();
  });
})
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/Byaqqm)

Comment: This is absolutely great Szymon honestly, I never even thought of doing these "hidden" divs, it's really good and it'll definitely help me in the future! Thanks!!